# Building a CSS grid layout with a repeating rows and a sparse header

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS grid for a layout and having trouble figuring out how to do so. Here's a sketch of the layout:

```
(empty)   | (empty)   | label     | (empty)
---------------------------------------------
col1      | col2      | col3      | col4
```

The bit I'm having trouble with, is that I want to repeat the second row as many times as necessary.

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to just throw the child elements in the grid container and have them flow into the correct spots without having to specify `grid-area` on them.

That is, ideally I can produce this layout with this markup:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>label</div>
  <div>col1</div>
  <div>col2</div>
  <div>col3</div>
  <div>col4</div>
</div>
```

I've been looking at grid documentation for an hour or so and can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;` for our `.label` div. Had to add a class to it. `1 / 3 / 2 / 4` means *grid-row-start / grid-column-start / grid-row-end / grid-column-end*. Basically we are placing `.label` in the third column of the first row with it. More about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area
2. We although can use `::before` as a first element with full width using `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5;`. `grid` treats `::before` like a first element.
3. Using `z-index` to set one element over another. `z-index` works some specific way for `grid` children. More here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout (Control of overlapping content)

Other children element works without specific `grid-area` setting, as you can see.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, auto);
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-container::before {
  content: '';
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5;
  z-index: 1; 
  background: cyan;
}
.grid-container .label {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="label">label</div>
  <div>col1</div>
  <div>col2</div>
  <div>col3</div>
  <div>col4</div>
  <div>col1</div>
  <div>col2</div>
  <div>col3</div>
  <div>col4</div>
</div>
```